# Norm estimates on $\log\big(\exp(X)\exp(Y)\big)$ using the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra of some Lie group $G$. Suppose that $\mathfrak{g}$ is equipped with some norm $\|\cdot\|$, so that for some $K>0$ we have $\|[X,Y]\|\leq K\|X\|\|Y\|$ for all $X,Y\in\mathfrak{g}$.

I would like to have some general and `useful' norm estimate on $\|\log\big(\exp(X)\exp(Y)\big)\|$, assuming that $\|X\|$ and $\|Y\|$ are sufficiently small, which is expressed in terms of $K$, $\|X\|$ and $\|Y\|$. This should be possible by applying the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula to $\log\big(\exp(X)\exp(Y)\big)$, and it looks like it must have been done before somewhere. Is there any reference?

Comment: Not sure, but there might be something in http://www.numdam.org/article/SB_1951-1954__2__255_0.pdf.